# how to avoid record fetching issues after deleting a user account

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Hey I'm trying to find a way to avoid record fetching issues when a user has been deleted.

I got a `posts table` and a `comments table`, both referencing to a `user_id`. If I delete the user it gives me an error page when the each-method is fetching data from either the posts or the comments table.

Thanks for advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add lines like this

```
has_many :posts, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
```

to User model, all posts and comments will be removed with the removed user.  If you want to keep the posts you can either instead of removing user record set some inactive flag, or create a special 'removed user' and pin all orphaned posts and comments to that user.

Comment: great thx. the inactive role sounds interesting. Yes Id like to keep posts and comments of a user. You got any advise here as well?